# What is the structure of an SQL dump file?

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-sql

I am using Firestore as my main database, but I would like to export its data to SQL format. In order to do that, I know I'll need to create a script to create/format the dump file. What is the standard way to structure the file contents? Is it XML? What are the required fields? Unfortunately, I cannot find the answer to this.

Additional Info:
I will be exporting data from Firestore and importing it to Google Cloud SQL.

EDIT 1:

I'm using Postgres.

Comment: I think you might want to consult the documentation for the SQL database you're using.

Comment: Typically there is a "dump" or "export" command or utility to do this for you. They often have various formats, and there is usually an option to dump as SQL statements. However that SQL is unlikely to be compatible with another database.

Comment: [Google Cloud SQL is just MySQL, Postgres, or SQL Server running in the Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/). They each have their own SQL variants. Which one do you intend to use? Look for how to transfer data from Firestore to your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I now understand that I'll be using Postgres. But I can't find a file structure using their docs.

Comment: @MartavisP. There is no simple way to do this. You're going from a NoSQL database to a SQL database. They use different paradigms for storing data. You'll have to think about how you'll translate your hierarchical NoSQL data into relational SQL, come up with a SQL schema, dump your data from Firebase, and translate it into a series of SQL INSERT statements. [Postgres JSONB columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-json.html) will help the transition, you could dump straight to JSONB and then restructure your data to better fit SQL after its inside Postgres.

Comment: Unless you have a very simple Firestore database, this will be difficult. PostreSQL is a SQL database, Firestore is a NoSQL database. The two can be very different in how data is stored (structured versus unstructured). If you can write (convert) Firestore into SQL statements, you can just write a script that will import into PostgreSQL. Writing the binary format will require the source code which is available.

Comment: I'm aware I would have to translate the data. My data is pretty flat, minus a couple of Firestore dates and objects/arrays. I can flatten those though. What I'm looking for is documentation that describes how to create a dump file to import. How do I declare a table, row, etc.?

Comment: If it helps, the larger context to this question is that my client is asking to do reporting with SQL queries. I am using [FireSQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firesql) but it has limitations - JOINS for instance. Also, I've written some custom code to help but it may get out of hand. So I'm trying to find the best solution.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the new Firebase Extension that automatically exports specific collections from Firestore to BigQuery: https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-bigquery-export/

Comment: @MartavisP. There's no magic. You write a text file with the SQL necessary to create the schema and add the data and feed it to the database. That means `create table` and `insert` and such. Then feed that SQL file to the database. You can do it from the command line with `psql < dump.sql`. There are potentially faster formats, see [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html), but this is simplest.

Comment: @Schwern I understand. I'm not looking for magic. I'm willing to create the dump myself using Nodejs but I'm trying to figure out how to do so. So I believe you are saying what I was looking for. To clarify, I need to create a `.txt` file with the SQL commands inside?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm looking into BigQuery now and that seems like the answer to my prayers! I wish I asked this question specifically in regards to giving you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the easiest way to get your data from Cloud Firestore in a more query-friendly format, have a look at the new [Firebase Extension that automatically exports specific collections from Firestore to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-bigquery-export/).

BigQuery is still a NoSQL database, but one that has built-in support for structured querying through a SQL dialect.